# Regarding sand box in our environment

Tags: sandbox, .net

Please send configuration/setup instructions to set up in our development (.NET) environment  and also prerequisites to set-up sand box environment in our end ? Thanks

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange. Your question is very vague. Is this related to salesforce sandboxes ? Elaborating your question with more details will help us answer you.

Comment: you do need to elaborate on your question, what are you trying to achieve? Have you salesforce experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download .net toolkit for salesforce
2. for sandbox creation and setup, https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm&language=en_US